# Which browser pioneered JIT-compiled JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, compilation, jit

I learn that, these days, all browsers JIT-compile JavaScript, and NOT interpret it.

I want to ask which browser pioneered this idea, i.e. introduced it for the very first time. I feel that it might be Google Chrome but there's absolutely no article out there to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [TraceMonkey](https://digitallibrary.un.org/js/pdfjs-2.9.359/web/pdf_viewer.html) was the first paper about a JIT for JS and it arrived in Firefox. It was presented in 2009 and its Related Work section mentions no other JS JITs -- just Psyco (precursor to PyPy) and some others. That being said, Chrome shipped V8 (including a JIT) with its release in 2008, so I would hazard a guess that they were developed in parallel. See more comments on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4630646).